# Github account change for AppVeyor's authorization to act

Tags: github, continuous-integration, appveyor

Recently I removed the writing rights of a former collaborator who left our github project.

Then I noticed that in the commits page there was no more report for the continuous integration tests with AppVeyer( by clicking on the red cross or the green check).

I gave again the write permission to this former collaborator and the report for AppVeyer became visible again.

So I looked more carefully at the features related to AppVeyor and this former collaborator. I saw that:

- in https://ci.appveyor.com/team at Account > Team > GitHub teams, I have not yet granted access to any GitHub teams and by clicking on CONFIGURE TEAMS I see that AppVeyor is authorized to act on behalf of this_former_collaborator GitHub account with admin:repo_hook, read:org, repo:status scope.
- in https://github.com, for our organization, by editing, in Seetings > Third-party access, the AppVeyor CI application, I see "approval requested by this_former_collaborator".

What can I do to remove the write rights to our Github project from this former contributor while keeping the results of the ongoing AppVeyor CI tests on the project commits page (and don't lose the history of the tests)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the fast and efficient help of AppVeyor's support team I was able to fixe this problem by [authorising AppVeyor as GitHub App](https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/26712-github-account-change-for-appveyors-authorization-to-act). Everything works fine now ...